# How to use firebase limits to paginate data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm used to php for backend, but I had to use firebase for this project cause of the realtime database...I am trying to paginate data loading. So far, I'm able to select the last 30 records using `limitTolast(30)`. However, after this I need to select 30 older records after the last 30 I previously selected for when the user scrolls to the top...Please how do I achieve this

I already tried `limtToLast(30).startAfter(30)`.
thank you.

UPDATE

I found a solution, using `endBefore(lastkey).limitToLast(1)`.However, its still not the best. The issue with this is, I would want to `limitToLast(10)` but if I do that, it runs the query 10 times with the same value as lastkey which causes repetition in my app. Please how can I fix this...What I would want is either get the `last 10 records before lastkey` once or allow me change the `lastkey` each time the query runs. I hope this makes sense

my code looks like this

```
this.db.child('messages/'+chatid).endBefore(this.state.messages[this.state.messages.length - 1].key).limitToLast(10).once('child_added', snapshot => this.parse(snapshot))
```

Comment: Firebase database APIs don't use offsets for pagination, but are based on knowing the values for the node you want to start after. I recommend checking out some previous questions on [pagination on Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-realtime-database%5d%5bjavascript%5d%20pagination) as this has been covered quite regularly before. Alternatively, edit your question to show a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see enough context to provide an answer.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks so much for your contribution. I checked the links and was able to find a solution, however a new issue came up. Please check my updated question.

Comment: The single line of code you provided does not explain the behavior you are asking about. Please show the [minimum code that we can copy/paste and run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).